# Strange behavior with getframe in MATLAB R2015b

Tags: matlab, opengl

I have encountered a very weird behaviour of the *getframe* function. I essentially create a new frame in a for loop by

```
figure(10)
image(xvekt*1e6,yvekt*1e6,I2/max(max(I2))*64)
hold on
plot(D_core/2*cos(linspace(0,2*pi,50))*1e6,D_core/2*sin(linspace(0,2*pi,50))*1e6,'Color',[1 1 1]*0.6,'LineWidth',2)
colormap(jet)
hold off
zoom(5)
drawnow
pause(.1)
F(steg_nummer) = getframe;
```

Exactly what the code does is not very important, but notice the *pause(0.1)* before the getframe call to make sure *getframe* really captures the frame. *steg_nummer* is the iteration variable.

After the for loop, I attempt to save the animation by

```
v = VideoWriter('C:\newfile.avi');
open(v);
for k=1:length(F)
 k
 writeVideo(v,F(k))
end
close(v)
```

But this fails. As above, I'm displaying the k for debugging purposes, and it appears that the *cdata* sometimes is a 0x0-matrix, which is weird.

The for loop

```
for k=1:length(F)
  disp(size(F(k).cdata))
end
```

returns

```
>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>     0     0

>   344   436     3
```

and *writeVideo* of course fails at the first 0x0 *cdata* matrix. I have tried switching to software OpenGL by *opengl('software')* in the beginning of the script, but without any luck. What is going on here?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to have proper formating. Put everything that is under `>` as code blocks, otherwise you are clogging the webpage with useless data. Aditionally, can you make a [mcve], something that we can reproduce without your data

Comment: @AnderBiguri There is no spoiler tag I could use, though.

Comment: With a `plot` instruction, the `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim` data of the axis are recalculated by matlab at every call, and can change depending on the actual data span. If you want a fized size frame, you have to set these limits manually. Look at my answer here on a very similar question: [how-to-generate-a-video-file-using-a-series-of-plots-on-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978938/how-to-generate-a-video-file-using-a-series-of-plots-on-matlab/27983031#27983031)

Comment: @Hoki This seems to be one of the problems, yes! The real problem was that I didn't plot all frames, but this also caused a problem. If you add this comment as an official answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that, Within your loop to `getframe`, the focus may change to some other windows due system or user activity etc. If this is the case, you can avoid the problem by specifying the handle of figure or axis as input to `getframe`:

```
hFig = figure(10); % return handle of the figure
...  % other code
F(steg_nummer) = getframe(hFig); % provide handle as input
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not resolve the problem. The stranger thing is that it's always the same frame that I lose.